# Elasticsearch Token filter for removing tokens with a single word

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have what seems to be a very simple problem though I can't get it to work.
I have a token stream of words and I want to remove any token that is a single word e.g. `[the quick, brown, fox]` should be outputted as `[the quick]`.

I've tried using `pattern_capture` token filters and used many types of patterns but it only generates new tokens, and doesn't remove old ones.

Here is the analyzer I've built (abbreviated for clarity)

```
"analyzer": {
  "job_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "char_filter": [
        "some_custom_char_filter"
      ],
      "filter": [
        other filters....,
        "dash_drop",
        "trim",
        "unique",
        "drop_single_word"
      ]
    }
  },
  "char_filter": {...},
  "filter": {
    "dash_drop": {
      "type": "pattern_capture",
      "preserve_original": false,
      "patterns": [
          "([^-]+)\\s?(?!-.+)",
          "- (.+)"
        ]
    },
    "drop_single_word": {
      "type": "pattern_capture",
      "preserve_original": false,
      "patterns": [**nothing here works**]
    }
  }
}
```

I know I'm using a `whitespace` tokenzier that breaks sentences into words, but not shown here is the use of `shingles` to create new nGrams.

The purpose of the `dash_drop` filter is used to split sentences with `-` into tokens without the `-` so for example: `my house - my rules` would split into `[my house, my rules]`.

Any help is greatly apperciated.

Comment: To match a string that has no space, you would use `^[^ ]+$` (or `[^ ]+` in Lucene regex)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, but I as I saw `pattern_capture` only adds new tokens, it doesn't remove the ones that don't match. How should I go about removing them?

Comment: How is the stream being fed into ES? Can you post your entire mapping?

Comment: @sramalingam24 sorry I can't. But can you clarify what you need to know? If you mean that I use logstash then no. I only need it to analyze individual sentences